# Beamsplitter complex notation

Tags: optics, complex-numbers, fiber-optics, laser-cavity

I am trying to understand the formalism presented in [this paper](https://www.hajim.rochester.edu/optics/sites/boyd/assets/pdf/publications/Heebner_JQE_04.pdf) about the transmission of a fiber ring resonator. By modelling the coupler as a beamsplitter, the authors write:

$$E_{2}=rE_{1}+itE_{3}$$
$$E_{4}=rE_{3}+itE_{1}$$

where $r,t$ are the amplitude-reflection/transmission coefficients.

> Why is it that for transmitted light there is an $i$ factor added in front of the amplitude? They are using complex notation ($i^2=-1$), but the paper does not explain why the waves acquire this factor.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

**P.S.** Here's a simplified diagram of the situation:

[image]

Comment: $i$ represent a phase difference of $180^0$ between transmitted wave  and the reflected wave .

Comment: The first section of [BeamSplitterInput-OutputRelations](http://www.pas.rochester.edu/~howell/mysite2/Tutorials/Beamsplitter2.pdf) might help you?